# How to select memory for motherboard when building a new machine?

Tags: memory, motherboard, computer-building

I am building a new PC. What resources do I use to ensure the ram I select is compatible with the motherboard I am selecting?

Currently, this is what I know.
The motherboard accepts a type of ram, like DDR3 double sided. A front bus speed which is a maximum, like 1600MHz
E.g. [ASRock B75M-DGS R2.0 - Memory Support List](http://www.asrock.com/mb/Intel/B75M-DGS%20R2.0/?cat=Memory)

The motherboard usually has a list of manufactourers of ram that is compatible. This list included module model numbers that do not completly correlate to the ram module model numbers I am looking at, as link above.

While hunting through ram, I find that the model numbers either do not match the list above at all or they match mostly.
E.g. G.Skill Sniper 8G Kit(4Gx2) DDR3 1600 **F3-12800CL9D-8GBSR**
However, the memory support list says: **F3-12800CL9D-8GBSR2** (extra 2 on the end).

So, how do I select ram? Do I take the memory support list as gospel; What about the partial match? Or is it as simple as being a DDR3, 1600MHz.

*Additional components in case they impact the question:

Intel i3 3220

ATI HD7770*

*When searching for this topic on the site, I only found specific instances of if a certain ram was compatible with a certain motherboard. Not a generic question such as this. Feel free to link any duplicate.*

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: thank you. i will delete this question as soon as you see this comment of thanks

Comment: lol, i cannot delete. Not enough rep.

Comment: Don't worry, it will be closed shortly. :-)

Answer (score 4):

My low tech way to doing this is to nearly always visit [Crucial.com](http://www.crucial.com/uk/store/listparts.aspx?model=B75M-DGS%20R2.0) and see if they list the pc/motherboard I'm looking to buy memory for. They do list your motherboard. Quite often I buy from Crucial but even if I don't I use their info to compare specifications with other vendors.

Answer (score 1):

The choice is yours.  The memory on the manufacturer page is the memory that they have tested with the board, and is ** officially** supported.  ANY DDR3-1600 (in capacities up to 8GB per stick) is supposed to be supported with the ivy-bridge CPU that you have selected and in my experience works just fine.